# Change the title of the edit button iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a tableview with an edit button on the left.

I created this edit button using

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

I want to know how to change the title of the Edit button to 'delete'

Cheers

Comment: Are you wanting to change the title of "Edit" button available in UIBarbuttonSystemItem type ?

Comment: is it possible ??
To be more clearer now when i click on the edit button, i have a red icon with minus sign on each of the table cells. I want to retain this, but only change the "edit" title to "delete"

Comment: I am not sure but you can try and take a edit button and then set its image which is having text as delete. I am not sure but you can give it a try. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the visual title of the edit button to 'Delete' is a bad idea -- you'll probably find your app gets rejected for doing something as ill advised as that. If it *does* get into the store, you'll confuse your users. Don't do it!

If you want a button called Delete that does something specific directly related to deleting that has a clear context, that's another matter. Note that destructive action buttons are usually a red colour, to signal to the user that there's a destructive action there, and sometimes pop up a UIActionSheet to confirm the user's destructive action.

Please read Apple' Human Interface Guidelines:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @occulus Correct me if i am wrong. When I set `self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=FALSE;` all that the user can do by clicking the 'EDIT' button is to delete. That is why i thought i will change the title to 'DELETE' Is it still a bad option ?

Comment: Narayanan, I see where you're coming from, but it's still a bad idea, because the word "Delete" appearing on the nav bar like that is completely devoid of context. The user will think something is about to be deleted, but what exactly? Everything? Something? I'd not even want to press such a button! In edit mode, it's clear what you're about to delete, because there's some context, with a delete control appearing next to the item you'd like to delete.

Comment: It would be much better just to leave the button as 'Edit'. Most iPhone users know that editing allows you to delete stuff. If deleting is all you can do, that's ok!

Answer (score 2):

You can just change button title. Here is the code

```
self.editButtonItem.title = @"Delete";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Doable, though it might not be a good idea. See [this answer by occulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297888/change-the-title-of-the-edit-button-iphone/5298087#5298087).**

Create a UIBarButtonItem as usual:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Whatever" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doSomething)] autorelease];
```

Then call `[self setEditing:!self.editing]` in `-(void)doSomething`.

Comment: Is it advisable to do this ? Reading from what Occulus says, i am having second thoughts if i should do this or not.

Comment: Honestly I think you shouldn't do this. The 'Delete' button might sound destructive to the user, thus discourage him from tapping the button.

Comment: -1 Very bad idea to do this. His app will probably get bounced out of the app store.

Comment: This is not what should be done. Apple doesn't approve this. Apple is very strict in terms of what it allows. So better not implement this.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"your title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Comment: No..i want the editing feature, but only the title to be changed.

Comment: To be more clearer now when i click on the edit button, i have a red icon with minus sign on each of the table cells. I want to retain this, but only change the "edit" title to "delete"